# Installing artoolkit with Ros

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

for my project I need to use Artoolkit with Ros. I downloaded the package from https://github.com/ar-tools/ar_tools but when I tried to compile I got the following error:

> Built target opencv_apps svn: E000110:
> Unable to connect to a repository at
> URL
> 'svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/artoolkit/code/trunk/artoolkit'
> svn: E000110: Can't connect to host
> 'svn.code.sf.net': Connection timed
> out make[2]: ***
> [ar_tools/artoolkit/ARToolkit-prefix/src/ARToolkit-stamp/ARToolkit-download]
> Interrupt make[1]: ***
> [ar_tools/artoolkit/CMakeFiles/ARToolkit.dir/all]
> Interrupt make: *** [all] Interrupt

Thinking that my university network blocks the svn I tried to use a VPN but without success:

> svn: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/artoolkit/code/trunk/artoolkit' svn: E670002: Unknown hostname 'svn.code.sf.net' make[2]: *** [ar_tools/artoolkit/ARToolkit-prefix/src/ARToolkit-stamp/ARToolkit-download] Error 1 make[1]: *** [ar_tools/artoolkit/CMakeFiles/ARToolkit.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2 Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

Without compiling the package I can't run some important nodes (e.g. ar_single). Did someone of you have the same problem and was able to solve it?

Edit: This is the result of the curl command

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: svn.code.sf.net

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227362/installing-artoolkit-with-ros/) by [pulver](https://answers.ros.org/users/22461/pulver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2016-02-23**:
Can you edit your answer to add the output of `curl -I svn.code.sf.net/p/artoolkit/code/trunk/artoolkit`? This will help us see what happens when you try to access the artoolkit repo.

**Comment by [AndraConnect](https://answers.ros.org/users/26068/andraconnect/) on 2016-02-25**:
Hi,

I would suggest posting your question on stack overflow or the ARToolkit community forum :) Someone more technical than me could be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried to compile from home instead from university and it worked. Apparently svn was blocked!
Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [pulver](https://answers.ros.org/users/22461/pulver/) with karma: 51 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0